# Laravel + Vue - Pass multidimensional PHP array to vue component

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, vue.js

In the file `config/variables.php` I have defined the following objects as a multidimensional array:

```php
<?php

return [
    [
        'name' => 'test1',
        'surname' => 'test1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'test2',
        'surname' => 'tes2'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'tes3',
        'surname' => 'test3'
    ]
];
```

I want to use this data in a Vue component, for example like this:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <div>Items:</div>
        <div v-for="i of items">
            {{ i.name }} {{ i.surname }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Test",
    props: {
        items: []
    }
}
</script>
```

I bring component and data together in a blade template that contains, among other, this:

```php
<div>Begin of test</div>
<Test :items="@json(Config::get('variables'))"></Test>
<div>End of test</div>
```

I would expect Laravel to pass the data on to the component which then renders a simple page containing the divs with the provided data. What I actually see in the browser is this:

```html
<div>Begin of test</div>
":"test1","surname":"test1"},{"name":"test2","surname":"tes2"},{"name":"tes3","surname":"test3"}]"="">
<div>End of test</div>
```

For one the data seems to get garbled in the process. Also the `<div>Items:</div>` of the component does not appear at all. So it seems the `@json` call somehow breaks the entire component. Same behaviour using `{!! json_encode(Config::get('variables')) !!}` instead. When I just output the config values directly into a div like `<div>@json(Config::get('variables'))</div>` the complete array is cleanly printed as JSON.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there!
You have just forgotten to escape the PHP in the element in your blade view.
It should be;

```
<div>Begin of test</div>
<Test :items="{{ json_encode(Config::get('variables')) }}"></Test>
<div>End of test</div>
```

If you want to use teh `@json` tag you need to drop the double quotes.
Example;

```
<div>Begin of test</div>
<Test :items=@json(Config::get('variables'))></Test>
<div>End of test</div>
```

I'm no JS expert, but I think this is due to when passing to `:items` (a shortcut for v-bind) it is treated as a JavaScript expression.

Comment: I'm stunned. Thought I tried everything. But why is it working with `@json` in a regular div then? Thank you, this solves it. Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @herhuf you can use the `@json` tag, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Update your variables.php

```html
<?php

$return = array(
  array(
   'name' => 'test1',
   'surname' => 'test1'
  ),
  array(
  'name' => 'test2',
   'surname' => 'tes2'
  ),
  array(
  'name' => 'tes3',
  'surname' => 'test3'
  )
);

echo json_encode($return);
```